Dart: extend an existing type with a new interface
How can I "add" a new interface to a type that I can't modify, such as int or DateTime, with minimal extra runtime costs?

Example
Consider this interface I wrote:
/// Represents a point in a real affine line.
///
/// A real affine line consists of points (of arbitrary type) that can be
/// translated by a real number, and the difference between two points is a real
/// number.
///
/// The type parameter [T] represents the type of points.
/// Should be used as a CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern).
abstract interface class Affine<T> {
  num difference(T other);

  T translate(num distance);
}

Right off the bat, the types int and DateTime, for example, could implement this interface.
But I can't modify these types directly.
So how can I add this funcitonality to these types?
Idea 1: Adapter
Write a wrapper class that adapts the existing type to this interface:
@immutable
class DateTimeToAffineAdapter implements Affine<DateTimeToAffineAdapter> {
  final DateTime dateTime;

  const DateTimeToAffineAdapter(this.dateTime);

  @override
  num difference(DateTimeToAffineAdapter other) {
    return dateTime.difference(other.dateTime).inMicroseconds;
  }

  @override
  DateTimeToAffineAdapter translate(num distance) {
    return DateTimeToAffineAdapter(
      dateTime.add(Duration(microseconds: distance.round())),
    );
  }
}

The problem with this approach is that I'm creating extra objects at runtime, one for each instance of the original type, just to add some methods to the latter.
Idea 2: extension methods
Extension methods can't implement an interface because they're essentially just static methods with some syntactic sugar.
Idea 3: extension types
I thought of extension types, as in extension type DateTimeToAffineAdapter(DateTime dateTime) implements Affine<...>, but I can't implement Affine because DateTime should implement it to start with in order for this to be a valid extension type.
Idea 4: redesign the interface
Instead of having an Affine<T> interface, have an AffineLine<T> interface:
abstract interface class AffineLine<T> {
  num difference(T a, T b);

  T translate(T point, num distance);
}

And then create just one instance for each wrapped type, e.g. AffineLine<DateTime> and AffineLine<int>.
But the usage of this new design is less elegant (because I would have to pass around an instance of AffineLine whenever I need to use the interface), and it might be that this type of redesign was only possible for this specific example.


How can I "add" a new interface to a type that I can't modify, such as int or DateTime, without incurring in extra runtime costs?

You cannot. Not with the current features of the Dart language.
The capability you get from an interface is late method resolution. You can call a method on something where you only know its type as an interface, and then the actual implementation is found on the object depending on its actual runtime type, at runtime.
The precise method of doing that method lookup is unspecified, but it is possible to use a "V-table", which means that the object itself carries around enough information to go from interface method to runtime method. It has to, since the call site doesn't know the actual runtime type of the object, and any class can implement an interface, so the call site cannot assume anything about the object layout.
Adding the ability to resolve a new interface method on an existing object without any runtime overhead is therefore impossible, because the object needs extra runtime information to make that lookup possible, information that isn't on the existing int or DateTime object.
There are different possible language features that makes it look like you can add interfaces to an object. Rust's traits is the classical example. A trait type incurs a runtime cost in Rust because trait-typed variables are "fat pointers", which combines a v-table for the trait type and the actual object reference. A fat pointer is basically an unboxed wrapper object with a single field, if you see an object as the combination of v-table and object state. The thing a trait saves over an (implicit) wrapper class is one indirection and having to have a name, at the cost of making all references take twice the space. (If you have to write the wrapper class yourself, it costs even more.)
In Rust, you opt in to something being a trait, there are non-trait types too.
In Dart, almost every type is an interface.

Ok, I should have been clearer. "No runtime costs" is too strong, and in my case I don't care about the low-level details of runtime costs of virtual methods etc. since I already use them everywhere with Dart; I should have written "with minimal runtime costs" or "less than a wrapper class". Thanks for your detailed insights anyway. In any case I think that indeed with the current language features there isn't much else other than the two ideas above.
